# no matching function for call to 'parseUserInput'

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a function that would "`parseUserInput()`" and my plan was to pass the user's input as an argument through the `parseUserInput()`'s "input" parameter. However, when I put anything into the "input" parameter, I get an error saying that there is "`no matching function for call to 'parseUserInput'`"

What is causing this error?

```
std::string branchCommand;
std::string userInputCmd;
std::string parsedInput;
std::string parseUserInput();

std::string inputCommand() {
    std::cin >> userInputCmd;
    parseUserInput(userInputCmd);

    return branchCommand;
}

std::string parseUserInput(std::string Input) {

    return parsedInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `parseUserInput` as `std::string parseUserInput();` which doesn't allow any arguments. If you want to pass an argument then change the declaration to match the function calling and function definition.

```
string parseUserInput(std::string Input) // declaration
```

Then you can call it like this: `parseUserInput(userInputCmd);`